# Exchange 2010 Outlook Anywhere (RPC over HTTP) not working (The EXCH provider section is missing from the Autodiscover response.)

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-anywhere

A bit of backstory... network exploded, rebuilt.  This AD has survived people not knowing what they are doing, Exchange 2007 (installed and removed a few times), Exchange 2010 (current in use and re-did from a crash once).

My Outlook Anywhere (RPC over HTTP) is not working, the XML response is below and as far as I can tell it's providing all the right information yet testexchangeconnectivity.com still says "The EXCH provider section is missing from the Autodiscover response."

I've gone through AD with a fine tooth comb and I believe everything is ok (everything is correct in Exchange service under configuration in ADSIEDIT), though I may not be looking in the right places.

My internal and external url are the same.  Any tips on where to look or any input is greatly appreciated!

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Autodiscover xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/autodiscover/responseschema/2006">
  <Response xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/autodiscover/outlook/responseschema/2006a">
    <User>
      <DisplayName>User Name</DisplayName>
      <LegacyDN>/o=Org/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=User Name</LegacyDN>
      <DeploymentId>1f6566b1-18f9-43ae-a2f4-495916449c3f</DeploymentId>
    </User>
    <Account>
      <AccountType>email</AccountType>
      <Action>settings</Action>
      <Protocol>
        <Type>EXCH</Type>
        <MdbDN>/o=Org/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Configuration/cn=Servers/cn=TRITON/cn=Microsoft Private MDB</MdbDN>
        <ASUrl>https://mail.domain.com/EWS/exchange.asmx</ASUrl>
        <OOFUrl>https://mail.domain.com/EWS/exchange.asmx</OOFUrl>
        <OABUrl>http://mail.domain.com/OAB/484c877c-a2ca-4ec7-b6eb-69c51c199245/</OABUrl>
        <UMUrl>https://mail.domain.com/EWS/UM2007Legacy.asmx</UMUrl>
        <Port>0</Port>
        <DirectoryPort>0</DirectoryPort>
        <ReferralPort>0</ReferralPort>
        <CertPrincipalName>msstd:*.domain.com</CertPrincipalName>
        <PublicFolderServer>ScuttleTwo.domain.com</PublicFolderServer>
        <AD>Dewey.students.domain.com</AD>
        <EwsUrl>https://mail.domain.com/EWS/exchange.asmx</EwsUrl>
        <EcpUrl>https://mail.domain.com/ecp</EcpUrl>
        <EcpUrl-um>?p=customize/voicemail.aspx&amp;exsvurl=1</EcpUrl-um>
        <EcpUrl-aggr>?p=personalsettings/EmailSubscriptions.slab&amp;exsvurl=1</EcpUrl-aggr>
        <EcpUrl-mt>PersonalSettings/DeliveryReport.aspx?exsvurl=1&amp;IsOWA=&lt;IsOWA&gt;&amp;MsgID=&lt;MsgID&gt;&amp;Mbx=&lt;Mbx&gt;</EcpUrl-mt>
        <EcpUrl-sms>?p=sms/textmessaging.slab&amp;exsvurl=1</EcpUrl-sms>
      </Protocol>
      <Protocol>
        <Type>EXPR</Type>
        <Server>mail.domain.com</Server>
        <ASUrl>https://mail.domain.com/EWS/exchange.asmx</ASUrl>
        <OOFUrl>https://mail.domain.com/EWS/exchange.asmx</OOFUrl>
        <OABUrl>https://mail.domain.com/OAB/484c877c-a2ca-4ec7-b6eb-69c51c199245/</OABUrl>
        <UMUrl>https://mail.domain.com/EWS/UM2007Legacy.asmx</UMUrl>
        <Port>0</Port>
        <DirectoryPort>0</DirectoryPort>
        <ReferralPort>0</ReferralPort>
        <SSL>On</SSL>
        <AuthPackage>Basic</AuthPackage>
        <CertPrincipalName>msstd:*.domain.com</CertPrincipalName>
        <EwsUrl>https://mail.domain.com/EWS/exchange.asmx</EwsUrl>
        <EcpUrl>https://mail.domain.com/ecp</EcpUrl>
        <EcpUrl-um>?p=customize/voicemail.aspx&amp;exsvurl=1</EcpUrl-um>
        <EcpUrl-aggr>?p=personalsettings/EmailSubscriptions.slab&amp;exsvurl=1</EcpUrl-aggr>
        <EcpUrl-mt>PersonalSettings/DeliveryReport.aspx?exsvurl=1&amp;IsOWA=&lt;IsOWA&gt;&amp;MsgID=&lt;MsgID&gt;&amp;Mbx=&lt;Mbx&gt;</EcpUrl-mt>
        <EcpUrl-sms>?p=sms/textmessaging.slab&amp;exsvurl=1</EcpUrl-sms>
      </Protocol>
      <Protocol>
        <Type>WEB</Type>
        <Port>0</Port>
        <DirectoryPort>0</DirectoryPort>
        <ReferralPort>0</ReferralPort>
        <Internal>
          <OWAUrl AuthenticationMethod="Basic, Fba">https://mail.domain.com/owa/</OWAUrl>
          <Protocol>
            <Type>EXCH</Type>
            <ASUrl>https://mail.domain.com/EWS/exchange.asmx</ASUrl>
          </Protocol>
        </Internal>
        <External>
          <OWAUrl AuthenticationMethod="Fba">https://mail.domain.com/owa/</OWAUrl>
          <Protocol>
            <Type>EXPR</Type>
            <ASUrl>https://mail.domain.com/EWS/exchange.asmx</ASUrl>
          </Protocol>
        </External>
      </Protocol>
    </Account>
  </Response>
</Autodiscover>
```

Comment: Is the test box asking the right server for this response? Maybe some remnant of the old configuration look for an older server that had the CAS role?

Comment: This response came from testexchangeconnectivity.com which is querying the external URL which is properly querying my CAS/HUB server.  There were existing CAS/HUB servers that no longer exist but everything should be removed from that, where abouts could I look for existing configs/info?

Comment: What was your resolution on this issue? I am seeing the same error (after removing an old multi-role server), and can't find much on this issue on google...

Comment: The below solution provided by snoopsmsc solved my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this same problem, and it took some digging, as the Exchange Remote Connectivity tool error message is quite misleading.

What this turned out to be, for me, was a reference to a CAS server that had recently been removed, in the databases' RPCClientAccessServer property.  (As a bit of background, Exchange is new in my environment, and I had set up Exchange with some 'test' hostnames.  Once it was time to move to production hostnames, I removed the test servers from the environment...)

The RPCClientAccessServer seems to not be set dynamically.  Obviously, as this is my initial Exchange implementation, I'm no expert, so if anyone can provide any more info on this, please indulge me.

Anyway, the resolution to this issue was as simple as grabbing the databases and resetting the RPCClientAccessServer property, using PowerShell.

For example, the following gets all databases on host "mailbox01", and sets the RPCClientAccessServer to "newCAS02":

```
    Get-MailboxDatabase -Server mailbox01.example.local | Set-MailboxDatabase -RPCClientAccessServer newCAS02.example.local
```

Note that these should be FQDNs.

To give credit where credit is due, I found my solution here http://exchangeserverpro.com/outlook-clients-unable-to-connect-to-exchange-2010-after-client-access-server-role-moved

I thought I'd post it here, because it mentions nothing about the "EXCH provider section missing" error, and this solution was a little tough to track down.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit difficult to diagnose based on the log report included.
I do see HTTPS in there so I would check to make sure you have imported your SSL cert.

You mentioned Exchange 2010 is what your running as of right now, have you taken it up to SP1? if you can do that and then follow the Microsoft TechNet article this should be the best place to start.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123741.aspx

there is also a powershell command Test-OutlookConnectivity

best of luck, let us know how it works out.

Comment: The SSL is imported and working fine, I assume when you say import you just mean setup IIS to use my cert .. it all pulls correctly using Microsofts testexchangeconnectivity tool.  I haven't gone to SP1 yet, though I plan to, would that make any difference with Outlook Anywhere?